# Get Image and Text From Server and show to gridview in android studio

Tags: android, api, gridview

i am using this example try it https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-custom-gridview-images/

but it is not working can you please help me to resolving this problem.

**"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference"**

this error has been shown

Comment: show your logcat and code

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-custom-gridview-images/

and logcat show


"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference"

Comment: this url  not working. thats why you getting null object reference

Comment: we are using another url it working correctly @siva35

Comment: post your code for better understanding.

Comment: if possible give the example to sloved the problem

Comment: Did you use the same url provided in the tutorial ? If yes it will not work as the url is not working. If not post your url codeor json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked out which tutorial you are following.The Url in that not working please check it.

Comment: This is comment not answer.